# Microsoft Outlook Customize Ribbon

Tags: outlook, ribbon

here is the official documentation of how to add a button to the Ribbon in Microsoft Outlook which will invoke some macros written by developer on click, looks very simple:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c

this is actually what i want to do but not manually. Is there way to do this programatically? I've searched about it, but nothing came out of it(.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ribbon can only be modified from a COM addin. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398246.aspx

Comment: Is that true? I think I customized my ribbon via File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon... But I do not know how to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420268/customize-outlook-ribbon-for-a-mailitem

Comment: I meant programmatically.