# Customize Outlook ribbon for a MailItem (via menus or VBA)

Tags: vba, outlook, customization, ribbon

Outlook has one ribbon displayed when the email index is shown, and a different ribbon when a MailItem is open.
I managed to add buttons to the Miscellaneous group in the ribbon for the index, via File -> Options.

Can I customize the ribbon for a MailItem via File -> Options?

Can I do this via VBA? Can this VBA be executed automatically at launch time?

Comment: The first half of the Question is not about programming. The second half is a duplicate. You may have to unaccept you answer before you delete this.

Comment: @niton - It is true that the first part of the quesion is not about programming, but it was convenient to post the two as a unit. The second is not a duplicate. I was not asking about any programmatic way of changing a ribbon, but only with VBA. Similar, but not dupe. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it via File -> Options. It was very simple, I had to access File -> Options from within the MailItem instead of the main window.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34791404/2707864), it apparently cannot be done via VBA.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the ribbon you want to customize
2. Click "Customize the Ribbon..."